# How to customize page not found error and internal error for 404 and 500 pages in play framework 1.2.x

Tags: playframework

I would like to direct the request to the `page not found page` (404.html) if `url` doesn't match a `route` and `action`. And also I would like to show a proper `message page` (500.html) if an error occured. I really could not get a clear answer from my searching in plays tutorial even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play 1.2.x already handles "Page not found" (404) and Application Errors (500) automatically!
You don't have to configure anything, it works out of the box.

Have a look in the folder `app/views/errors/`, here you can find the default 404.html and 500.html. You can customize them for your needs.

Comment: however when I try to start play app in prod mode, stil dev 404 is working. do you have any idea why? or do I not manage to start play in prod mode?

Comment: is this facility available in play2.2.5 version?